# How to combine two Angularjs form validation directives conditions in CSS?

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I want the input fields to have red bg when both $dirty and $invalid is true but you I can only do it one by one which is not right.

```css
input.ng-dirty && input.ng-invalid {
    background-color:pink;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want *both* to be true, you have to do the following:

```css
input.ng-dirty.ng-invalid {
    background-color:pink;
}
```

```html
<input class="ng-dirty ng-invalid"/>
<input class="ng-invalid"/>
<input class="ng-dirty"/>
```

With this code, you apply the styling if either class is set on the element.

```css
input.ng-dirty, input.ng-invalid {
    background-color:pink;
}
```

```html
<input class="ng-dirty"/>
<input class="ng-invalid"/>
```